# Cross edition exception handling with Powershell web cmdlets

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have an existing PowerShell module that runs against Windows PowerShell 5.1. It depends heavily on the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlets which have some [fairly significant changes](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/11/powershell-core-web-cmdlets-in-depth.html) between 5.1 and PowerShell Core 6.

I've already managed to make most of the code work between editions (Desktop/Core), but the last thing I'm having trouble with is handling the exceptions thrown by HTTP failure responses.  The existing code looks more or less like this.

```
try {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest @myparams -EA Stop
    # do more stuff with the response
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    # parse the JSON response body for error details
}
```

I don't necessarily want to trap any exceptions other than the ones generated by failing HTTP response codes from the server. The exception type returned on Core edition is different than Desktop edition and requires separate code paths to parse the response. So initially I tried this:

```
try {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest @myparams -EA Stop
    # do more stuff with the response
} catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    # Desktop: parse the JSON response body for error details
} catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException] {
    # Core: parse the JSON response body for error details
}
```

This works fine when running in Core. But when running in Desktop, I get a `Unable to find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException]` error.

What's the best way to work around this? Do I need to just catch all exceptions, string match on the type, and re-throw what I don't want? Is there a more elegant way I'm missing that doesn't involve releasing separate versions of the module for Desktop and Core versions of PowerShell?

Comment: I would indeed go the text way. `catch [Exception]`, then switch on `$_.Exception.GetType().FullName` and have a default `throw` action. That should work fine cross platform and hasn't more codelines than your sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might recommend that you make thin wrapper around the cmdlets that does exception handling, and maybe you create a consistent exception class of your own and each version throws the same one.

At run time, you determine your version/edition, and set an alias to which one you want to use.

Example:

```
function Invoke-PS51WebRequest {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(...)

    try {
        Invoke-WebRequest @PSBoundParameters -EA Stop
        # return the response
    } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        # create a new exception
        throw [My.Custom.Exception]$_
    }
}

function Invoke-PS6XWebRequest {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(...)

    try {
        Invoke-WebRequest @PSBoundParameters -EA Stop
        # return the response
    } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        # Desktop
        throw [My.Custom.Exception]$_
    } catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HttpResponseException] {
        # Core
        throw [My.Custom.Exception]$_
    }
}

switch ($PSVersionTable)
{
    { $_.Is51 } { Set-Alias -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Value Invoke-PS51WebRequest -Force }
    { $_.Is6X } { Set-Alias -Name Invoke-WebRequest -Value Invoke-PS6XWebRequest -Force }
}

try {
    Invoke-WebRequest @myParams -ErrorAction Stop
} catch [My.Custom.Exception] {
    # do something
}
```

This needs a lot of work (parsing the exceptions properly, maybe making more than 2 of these variations, determining which platform you're on for real as `$PSversionTable.Is51` and `.Is6X` aren't real, creating your own exception class, creating a proper instance of it instead of casting `$_` to it, etc.).

I also demonstrated overriding the actual name `Invoke-WebRequest`, but I recommend using your own name `Invoke-MyCustomWebRequest` and using that throughout your code instead. It will keep things more manageable.

Comment: The function that does the error handling now is already sort of a wrapper for Invoke-WebRequest that returns a custom exception type parsed from the response body. So it might not be as much work to make this go. Thanks for the idea. I'm curious what other answers people might come up with. But I'll mark this as accepted if nothing else substantial is added.